# Storing files in SQL vs Storing in web server's HDD

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, file-upload

so I have this site in asp.net, which allows user to upload and save their important files to server, which on demand of user (when user logins and views his files and clicks on one of his file) are allowed to be downloaded to clients computer.
Also, the size of file allowed to save is less then 25Mb (at least for now!), the files can be only any type, including but not limited to .txt, .rtf, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .jpg, .png etc.
So, the question is where should I store the files considering the best performance, should I store files in SQL Server (using SQL server 2008 just so you know, visual studio 2008 sp1) in a column (in BLOB format possibly?) or should I store them in HDD of server.
Also, considering the max size, say, even if 10 users uploaded files of, say 20Mb, this would occupy 200Mb of storage! If anyone can tell, how much would this cause to increment in size of database if these file were stored in database?
I mean how much space requirement would grow in database relative to storage in file system, also which would be better in performance?

Comment: Personally I like to store files on the File System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Microsoft paper: [To Blob or not](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

IMHO - there are lots of benefits and drawbacks in both methods - to store files in DB and to store them in FS

**BUT** for sql server 2008 there is an another option - to store files in FileSYstem as part of DB, see [FILESTREAM overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would always use disk storage for file data like this. The database is ultimately storing file data on disk anyway just with an additional layer of cost and abstraction. The abstraction invariably adds scaling and performance barriers. For example its easier to transition from file on local HDD to file in a CDN than from a database and its a lot easier to add more disk space when you need it without having to extend the size of your database.

I have built similar systems to the one you describe in the past, from experience its worth investing some time in thinking about the abstraction in the way your store files so it can be swapped out or updated.

Comment: Agreed. however additional layer could give you same extra features like consistent backup policy or replication

Comment: True, although disk based backup is likely to be more cost effective.

Comment: but needs to be set up separately ;-) People are likely to forget about these kind of things :D

Answer (score 0):

According to the msdn document that Oleg provided and some other benchmarks/opinions available for smaller files (~0.25MB and less) using db could be considerable faster, however I would keep that solution for extreme well-grounded purposes only. For most cases I would say storing files on HDD is more suitable, flexible and... natural.

However, I you shouldn't limit your analysis to the performance only. Take into account different aspects like:

- security
- backups
- scalability (ex. replication)

which usually require extra attention when using additional data sources.